# `require': no such file to load -- sinatra/base (LoadError) when running a Sinatra app (resque-web)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sinatra, resque

I'm running the PHP version of Resque and would like to use the Sinatra frontend app that comes with the Ruby version of Resque. (https://github.com/defunkt/resque-web)

**Problem:** On my Ubuntu box, I installed Ruby, Gems, and Sinatra. When I tried to start `server.rb`, I get an error as shown below.

Having almost no experience in Ruby, any help getting this app to work will be awesome :)

**Error**

```
server.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- sinatra/base (LoadError)
    from server.rb:1
```

**What I Did**

```
git clone https://github.com/defunkt/resque-web.git
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential
sudo apt-get install rubygems
gem install sinatra
cd resque-web
ruby server.rb
```

**Ruby**

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

### Attempt 2

Its probably getting worse...

**Added to the top of server.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
```

**Error**

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- resque (LoadError)
```

---

### Attempt 3

```
gem install resque
ruby server.rb
```

**Error**

```
[WARNING] MultiJson is using the default adapter (ok_json). We recommend loading a different JSON library to improve performance.
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque/helpers.rb:6: Please install the yajl-ruby or json gem (RuntimeError)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/resque-1.23.0/lib/resque.rb:10
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `gem_original_require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
        from server.rb:4
```

**Did:**

```
gem install json gem
ruby server.rb
```

**Error**

```
:public is no longer used to avoid overloading Module#public, use :public_folder instead from server.rb:13
```

---

### Attempt 4

Changed

```
    set :public, "#{dir}/server/public"
```

to

```
    set :public_folder, "#{dir}/server/public"
```

Now when I `ruby server.rb`, nothing happens and I get back the shell...

Comment: Did you gem install resque ?

Comment: Nope, I just need the sinatra app. Let me gem install resque and see what happens

Comment: `gem install resque` and seems like there is some progress... getting a different error now *(edited original post)*

Comment: In here it says: https://github.com/defunkt/resque if you have installed resque as gem,you just have to run resque-web on the command line

Comment: Awesome it works now! So I shouldnt git clone the resque-web repo? And I should install `resque` using gems and do resque-web from there to start the frontend app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install Resque using gems,`gem install resque` and just run resque-web from the command line. Refer: github.com/defunkt/resque